# Asp Net Boilerplate hosting with Hangfire dashboard

Tags: hangfire, aspnetboilerplate

I am having a problem where even after enabling the AbpHangfireAuthorizationFilter for the hangfire dashboard I am still met with a 401 when attempting to navigate to the HangFire dashboard.
This is due to the fact that the cookie is not sent with the request because the front end project and the backend api are on separate subdomains

I should clarify that we have the api in an Azure App Service by itself and the web front end in a separate Azure App Service. Thus the two pieces end up with different sub domains. The UI is still able to call the api because of the CORS setup that exists on the api.

Are the front end and back end meant to be deployed to the same sub domain? If not what are the steps I need to take to get the Hangfire dashboard up?

Comment: This is probably related to https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/1971 I will be happy if someone used hangfire like that can suggest a way of that.

Comment: For the hangfire configuration 

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/1245

Comment: The above recommended solution to this no longer works with Abp latest .netcore 2.0 releases.

An updated process for providing access to the Hangfire dashboard via token authentication would be appreciated. I have been banging my head against this for hours now and the documentation on https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Hangfire-Integration for AspNet.Core simply does not work.

has anyone had any recent success with this?